# Local function declarations should be put before or after "return"

Tags: javascript, conventions

What are the pros and cons?
Is there a consensus or good practice established for this case?
What says linters tools, code conventions and standard guides about that?

```
function before(){
  // declare variables

  function x(){
  }

  // do stuff

  return x();
}

function after(){
  // declare variables
  // do stuff

  return y();

  // ------------------------
  function y(){
  }
}
```

Another example:

```
var Person = function(name) {
  var person = {
    name: name,
    smile: smile,
    talk: talk
  };

  // here alongside function execution?
  function talk() {
  }

  return person;

  // or here, after return statement?
  function smile(){
  }
};
```

Comment: It's easier to read through if the return is last and that's almost always where you'll see them for a function. Plus it just looks better.

Comment: What is the benefit of putting them after?

Comment: Function declarations are hoisted, so it doesn't matter, but having anything after `return` is generally poor practice.

Comment: #3: Put local function declarations at the top, then do stuff with them, then `return`.

Comment: Both code execution results undefined .. then why you are using them this way. Why dont you create an object ?

Comment: @UmairKhalid in this _illustrative_ example - yes, they return `undefined`. The functions `x` and `y` could, of course, return any values be they static or not. I fail to see how an object is in any way relevant to the question.

Comment: @Bergi, I've updated the question.. the stuff before declaration was supposed to be variable declarations.

Comment: @UmairKhalid I provided a very simple example, the outside function could be a class or a module, local functions could be the methods, being declared aside the returning object.

Comment: I still do not _potato_ what the advantage of _zebra_ a function after the `return` statement is. In the previous sentence read _potato_ as "see" and _zebra_ as "placing".

Comment: @vlaz I've seen that pattern somewhere in github - more than once..

Comment: @AndreFigueiredo that's one late reply...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a matter of personal choice and both has got and sweet side.

In the later case it's useful when developer needs to read quickly how functions are invoked at the top of the source file, without the necessity to scroll down and read the details about function implementation.

A style close to the second one is followed when binding member in angular js.
[**Here**](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#bindable-members-up-top) is a link for recommended style-guide on how angular js binding members up top

Answer (score 0):

Since functions get hoisted up the scope, there's no real difference, only preference.
**return**'s natural place is at the end, so why not have it there?